# What's the derivative with respect to a constant?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have $f(x) = 5x$.

I know that $\frac{d\ f(x)}{dx} = 5$.

But what is $\frac{d f(x)}{d 5}$ , the derivative of the function $f$ with respect to the constant 5?

The reason I ask is that I'm implementing software that computes auto-differentiation (a la TensorFlow). I want to know if I can treat a constant like a variable (as above) or if I have to do something else. This [Stanford deep learning class webpage](https://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/) is what I'm referring to:

> $$
> f(x) = c+x \\
> f_a(x) = ax
> $$
> Where the functions $f_c$, $f_a$ translate the input by a constant of $c$ and scale the input by a constant of $a$, respectively. These are technically special cases of addition and multiplication, but we introduce them as (new) unary gates here since we do not need the gradients for the constants $c$, $a$.

That above statement implies that you *could* compute the derivative w.r.t. a constant, but they chose not to.

This post did not answer my question:
[derivative with respect to constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360807/derivative-with-respect-to-constant)

Thanks.

Comment: You my friend, have been watching too much Flammable Maths

Comment: It is ill defined since you cannot define the incremental ratio

Comment: "derivative of f with respect to x" is interpreted as "if I change x a little, what happens to f?" Since constants don't change, you can't put c in the place of x.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of a constant with respect to a variable is $0$, but the derivative of a function with respect to a constant, as Fra mentioned in the comments, is ill defined.

**EDIT**

The question has been updated. The link provided in the question discusses functions

$$f_c(x) = c + x $$
and
$$f_a(x) = ax$$

The link also indicates their derivatives are:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=1$$
and
$$\frac{df}{dx}=a$$
respectively, as expected.

These derivatives are still with respect to $x$, not constants $c$ or $a$. The confusion might have arisen since letter $c$ in $f_c(x)$ might have given the impression that this is a function with respect to $c$, which is not the case. Same argument applies for $f_a(x)$.

Comment: $\frac{d\ 5x}{d5} = x$, right?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 no. I believe you are treating this as a fraction, but derivative should be treated as a fraction. $5$ is a constant so $\frac{d (5x)}{d5}$ is not defined. You can talk about $\frac{d (5x)}{dx}$, which is equal to 5. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

It help to know about the [Derivation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) that satisfies
$$ D_t[u+v] = D_t[u]+D_t[v],\quad D_t[u\,v] = D_t[u]\,v + u\,D_t[v].\tag{1} $$
For example, use equation $(1)$ to get
$$ D_t[m\,x+b] = D_t[m]\,x + m D_t[x] + D_t[b].\tag{2} $$
You asked

> I want to know if I can treat a constant like a variable

In the context of symbolic differentiation the answer is yes
with $\,D_t,\,$ and if you want to assume laterthat some
symbol $\,c\,$ is a constant, you just set $\,D_t[c] = 0.\,$

Mathematica has a function [Dt](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html) which implements the total differential.

Answer (score 1):

A derivative is defined by a limit
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dx}(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
\end{equation}
and that means how $f$ changes when $x$ changes if $x$ is constant, then $x$ never changes so we can interpret $f$ never changes but this has not sense. Anothe way (matemathecally) that limit does not exist because the limit at the denominator is $0$ $\forall x$.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of computation graphs used for auto-differentiation (like in TensorFlow) for neural network back-propagation, constants (e.g. 5) can be treated like an input variable.

In the case of the original example,

$$
f(x) = 5x
$$
Then
$$
\frac{d f(x)}{d 5} = x 
$$

Note that in practice, while $\frac{d f(x)}{d 5}$ is computable, you would never need the result because the point of autodifferentiation for backpropagation is to update weight variables.